# Android Studio Firebase Application error?

Tags: java, android, xml

Following a tutorial on android development and I ran across errors, having a couple of errors when I try to create EditTextTitle and EditTextDescription variables. Also when I try to pass the (View v) parameter in the saveNote method the same error appears, below is my XML file and Java main code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="saveNote"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.firestoreapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //constants, variables that cannot change essentially
    //logt shortcut
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    //title
    //description
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    //idk why this is not working
    private EditText editTextTitle;
    private EditText editTextDescription;

    //reference for firebase database
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //
        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        editTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_description);
    }

    public void saveNote (View v) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `button` element tag in your layout should be changed to `Button` as follows.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:onClick="saveNote"/>
```

Comment: Fixed it, but the issue still persists, I am getting cannot find symbol class EditText.

Comment: You might have to clean and build the project again.

Comment: Tried that, clean project then build project but the EditText variable is still red, compiler could not find symbol. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: @Jaber2599 did you mean that, `EditText` color red?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it is red, when I press alt + enter, it disappears but I have no clue what that did? The person running the tutorial seems to write that code and doesn't turn red? What am I doing wrong?